# Add query parameter to url in axios

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs, axios

I am implementing axios query but not able to pass the query parameters in the url.

for example :

```
const url = /admin/list;

return axios.get(url,{
        params: {
            foo: 'bar'
        }
    }
);
```

but when I look at the Network tab the url is only

```
https://localhost:3001/admin/list
```

and not

```
https://localhost:3001/admin/list&foo=bar
```

How can I append the url with the query parameter .
I have 5 query parameters to be passed in the url , this foo is just for an example.

How to pass all the query parameters as a variable.

Comment: Why don't you just modify the `url` variable? Think thats actually how you need to do it according to the manual.

Comment: thats the end resort.

Comment: `return axios.get('/admin/list?foo=bar')`

Comment: Should work fine as shown

Comment: @putvande this I know is working but is there no way I can pass them as a separate parameter. I have 5-6 query parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own path builder

```
const baseUrl = "admin/list"
const params = {
     foo: 'bar'
}
let paramsUrl = ""

Object.keys(params).map((key, index)=>{
    const p = key + "=" + parmas[key]
    paramsUrl += index==0 ? p : '&' + p
}

return axios.get(baseUrl  + paramsUrl ? '?' + paramsUrl : '')
```